# Can I connect TV Speakers to an interface and use them as stand alone?

Tags: speakers, interface, tv

A couple of months ago I broke my TV and the only thing I could kept were the internal TV speakers

[image]

[image]

The TV was an LG 55EA9800.

Now, my laptop has been giving me issues with the sound, I think the internal speakers might be broken as well, that's why I was thinking that maybe , there is a way in which I can use some sort of interface, like a universal driver board to connect the speakers to it, and use a cable to run the sound from the laptop to the interface and use the TV speakers as external sound for my laptop/any other device with an audio jack.

If possible, can you please advise which kind of board should I get considering the connector used by the speakers?

Regards,

Comment: sorry didn't mean to violate the guidelines, I really didn't have a clue about what I needed, but the answer really helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It is called an amplifier. Match the Impedance and Wattage of the speakers for best performance. Thats normally written on the speakers inside that plastic.

A classic Class D amp would work,  but there are millions of types available.

The connector is unimportant here,  but it looks like a standard JST type connector, likely 2mm between pins. Cut them off and solder directly.

Comment: Note that this answer is correct if those ugly plastic boxes just contain loudspeaker drive units. If that assumption's wrong, and there's some electronics in there ... all bets are off.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you pointed me in the right direction, and yes they're loudspeakers, actually I don't know much about electronic, but I followed your advise about cutting the connector, it never occurred to me cause I thought it would ruin the speakers, and I happened to have a device with some push type speaker terminal connectors, I connected the wires and it actually worked!, sound pretty good!

Comment: @vic keep in mind that the Inductance and Wattage of the speakers are important. Not matching the speakers to the amp can lead to one or the other blowing out.

Comment: yeah I think it should be fine each speaker has an impedance of 8 and I'm using a wireless transmitter that supports a wide range of impedance, it says that the minimum impedance value should be 4, so I guess it shouldn't be a problem